# How do I create the padded message for use in the SHA256-2 algorithm?

Tags: utf-8, sha256, sha, rsa-sha256

I am trying to understand the SHA-2 algorithm.  And it seems that its a bit vague on how people are encoding the message 'L'   (see wikipedia's SHA256-2 pseudo code).  Is the message encoded in ASCII, UTF-8, or UTF-16? I understand that technically message L could be anything that we decide before encrypting but I want to check my little test program with other sites like https://www.dcode.fr/sha256-hash  and I realize I can't even check anything (except the empty "") without knowing if we are padding the '1' and subsequent '0's to the 9 bit representations for the message or 16 bit representations for the message. If I use the ASCII (which in this case is the same as UTF-8) for the word 'dcode' I am expecting the message to start with the following binary sequence:

`d:01100100:UTF-8:100
c:01100011:UTF-8:99
o:01101111:UTF-8:111
d:01100100:UTF-8:100
e:01100101:UTF-8:101
0110010001100011011011110110010001100101`

can someone verify that I'm thinking of this correctly?  And as a side benefit if you know where the standard that says the pre-hashed message should be UTF-8 or UTF-16 (presumably for specific applications) it would be much appreciated.

This answer is close but lacks specificity in its answer

[How can i pad the message in sha family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547473/how-can-i-pad-the-message-in-sha-family)

Answer (score 2):

The encoding doesn't matter.  The "message L" is just a bunch of bits.  Text can be encoded in any encoding you like.  It is the *bits* of the final encoding that are processed by the SHA256 algorithm, so you'll get different answers if text is encoded in UTF8 or UTF16.

When you receive a message, the SHA256 can be validated and *then* the message can be decoded.  The sender would have to tell you both the expected SHA256 and the encoding of the text.

FYI, the site linked<sup>1</sup> used the ASCII values of the characters to generate the hash listed. Make sure to use `dCode` not `dcode` as in the question. Python code below:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256('dCode'.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
'254cd63ece8595b5c503783d596803f1552e0733d02fe4080b217eadb17711dd'
```

As far as padding is concerned, the message (in this case "dCode") is five bytes (40 bits).  According to Wikipedia SHA-256:

> *Pre-processing (Padding):*
> begin with the original message of length L bits
> append a single '1' bit
> append K '0' bits, where K is the minimum number >= 0 such that (L + 1 + K + 64) is a multiple of 512
> append L as a 64-bit big-endian integer, making the total post-processed  length a multiple of 512 bits
> such that the bits in the message are:  1  <L as 64 bit integer> , (the number of bits will be a multiple of 512)

So "dCode" is 5 bytes (40 bits).  At least 9 more bytes must be added (the 1 bit and 7 more K bits to make 1 byte, plus the 64-bit (8-byte) bit-endian value of L.  That makes 14 bytes.  64 bytes are needed to make a message that is modulo 512 bits, so 50 more zero bytes must be added before the final 8-byte length.  In Python that would be:

```py
>>> def preprocess(msg):
...     # original message length in bits
...     L = len(msg) * 8
...     # append another byte binary 10000000 + the 8-byte big-endian L
...     msg += b'\x80' + L.to_bytes(8,'big')
...     n = len(msg) * 8      # new total length
...     if n % 512 != 0:      # if not modulo 512
...         n = 512 - n % 512 # how many more bits needed
...         n //= 8           # convert to bytes
...         # Python magic to insert n bytes in the right place
...         msg = msg[:L // 8 + 1] + b'\x00' * n + msg[L // 8 + 1:]
...     return msg
...
>>> preprocess(b'dCode').hex()
'64436f64658000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000028'
>>> len(preprocess(b'dCode'))  # in bytes
64
```

Caveat: The above algorithm assumes messages that are multiples of 8 bits in size (byte-oriented messages), but SHA-256 supports any bit length.

<sup>1</sup>*SHA-256* on dCode.fr [online website], retrieved on 2022-06-12, https://www.dcode.fr/sha256-hash